# The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I have 2 tables in SQL. One is called `Training` and one is called `Consultants`. Training is couple of fields like `ID, Place, Time, Date` and it also has `ConsultantName` which is foreign key and is connected with `Consultants` having ConsultantName, ConsultantFirstName etc.

During save of Training i save the training first and then pass the Training value as varTraining. I tried to attatch it to context as per some suggestions I found on stack but it doesn't seem to work:

```
Training Training = context.Trainings.First(p => p.TrainingID == varTraining.TrainingID);
                context.Trainings.Attach(Training);
                currentUczestnik.Training = Training;
```

Here's the code:

```
        using (var context = new EntityBazaCRM(Settings.sqlDataConnectionDetailsCRM))
        {
            Training Training = context.Trainings.First(p => p.TrainingID == varTraining.TrainingID);
            foreach (var currentUczestnik in listaUczestnikow)
            {
                context.Trainings.Attach(Training);
                currentUczestnik.Training = Training;
                if (context.TrainingUczestnicies.Any(t => t.TrainingUczestnicy1 == currentUczestnik.TrainingUczestnicy1))
                {
                    context.TrainingUczestnicies.Attach(currentUczestnik);
                    context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(currentUczestnik, EntityState.Modified);
                }
                else
                {
                    // context.Detach(currentUczestnik.Consultant);
                    context.Consultants.Attach(currentUczestnik.Consultant);
                    context.TrainingUczestnicies.AddObject(currentUczestnik);
                    //context.TrainingUczestnicies.Attach(
                }
            }
            try
            {
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string excepion = ex.InnerException.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(excepion);
            }

        }
```

Edit:

The full story looks like this.

There is this Table with Consultants. People are loaded with:

```
using (var context = new EntityBazaCRM(Settings.sqlDataConnectionDetailsCRM)) {       
    IQueryable<Konsultanci> listaKonsultantow = from k in context.Konsultancis select k;      
    objectListViewKonsultanci.SetObjects(listaKonsultantow); 
}
```

They are loaded into ObjectListview. Then when user clicks on that ObjectListView the following Consultants are "copied" into ObjectListView Participants.

```
        foreach (Konsultanci konsultant in objectListViewKonsultanci.SelectedObjects) {
            dodajUczestnikowSzkolen(konsultant);
        }
```

New object is created called SzkolenieUczestniczy (Participants) and Consultant is assigned to it as it's connected. Some more properties are added too.

```
    private void dodajUczestnikowSzkolen(Konsultanci konsultant) {
        SzkolenieUczestnicy nowyUczestnik = new SzkolenieUczestnicy();
        nowyUczestnik.Konsultanci = konsultant;

        //nowyUczestnik.SzkolenieUzytkownik = Settings.currentlyLoggedKonsultant.KonsultantNazwa;
        nowyUczestnik.SzkolenieUzytkownikData = DateTime.Now;
        //listaUczestnicy.Add(nowyUczestnik);
        objectListViewUczestnicy.AddObject(nowyUczestnik);
    }
```

Now users saves Training (some fields like Date, Time, Topic were attached to to currentSzkolenie (Training):

```
    private void sqlZapiszSzkolenie() {

        using (var context = new EntityBazaCRM(Settings.sqlDataConnectionDetailsCRM)) {
            if (context.Szkolenies.Any(t => t.SzkolenieID == currentSzkolenie.SzkolenieID)) {
                context.Szkolenies.Attach(currentSzkolenie);
                context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(currentSzkolenie, EntityState.Modified);
            } else {
                context.Szkolenies.AddObject(currentSzkolenie);
            }


            context.SaveChanges();
            context.Detach(currentSzkolenie);

        }
    }
```

So after I saved Training and the Training is now in database I head off to save Participants. I take `currentSzkolenie` (global var for Training) and pass it as variable:

```
 private void sqlZapiszUczestnikow(ObjectListView listaUczestnikow, Szkolenie varSzkolenie) {


        foreach (SzkolenieUczestnicy currentUczestnik in listaUczestnikow.Objects) {
            using (var context = new EntityBazaCRM(Settings.sqlDataConnectionDetailsCRM)) {
                  Szkolenie szkolenie = context.Szkolenies.First(p => p.SzkolenieID == varSzkolenie.SzkolenieID);

                  context.Attach(szkolenie);
                  currentUczestnik.Szkolenie = szkolenie;
              //  currentUczestnik.Szkolenie.EntityKey = szkolenie.EntityKey;
                if (context.SzkolenieUczestnicies.Any(t => t.SzkolenieUczestnicy1 == currentUczestnik.SzkolenieUczestnicy1)) {
                    context.SzkolenieUczestnicies.Attach(currentUczestnik);
                    context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(currentUczestnik, EntityState.Modified);
                } else {
                    // context.Detach(currentUczestnik.Konsultanci);
                    context.Konsultancis.Attach(currentUczestnik.Konsultanci);
                    context.SzkolenieUczestnicies.AddObject(currentUczestnik);

                    //context.SzkolenieUczestnicies.Attach(
                }

                try {
                    context.SaveChanges();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    string excepion = ex.InnerException.ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show(excepion);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

And that's about it.. it throws error on  `currentUczestnik.Szkolenie = szkolenie;`

Comment: Reading the exception my guess would be that the objects in `listaUczestnikow` are already attached to another context. Is that possible? Where do you get this list from?

Comment: The error comes up on currentUczestnik.Training = Training; rather then on listaUczestnikow. ListaUczestnikow is simple List<> that isn't connected to anything other then keeping Consultants that are already in database.. those consultants are in database and I want them to be assigned to Training.

Comment: Yes, but `currentUczestnik` is an object in the list, that's what I meant. `Consultants` already in the database??? Did you load them from the database using another context which isn't disposed yet?

Comment: Yes, I loaded them from database to ObjectListView and there's no .Detach context.. maybe that's it. But I've got it inside using shouldn't it dispose context when Consultants are put into ObjectListView?

Comment: using (var context = new EntityBazaCRM(Settings.sqlDataConnectionDetailsCRM)) {
                IQueryable<Konsultanci> listaKonsultantow = from k in context.Konsultancis
                                                            select k;
      
                objectListViewKonsultanci.SetObjects(listaKonsultantow);
                
            }

Comment: Can you describe the stuff of your last two comments in your question, I think that part is very important for your question. I don't know if disposing is enough, maybe there are references to the old, yet disposed context in the EntityObjects/EntityCollections which are causing the problems when you attach to the new context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with 2 solutions.

1. I have declared `private EntityBazaCRM context = new EntityBazaCRM(Settings.sqlDataConnectionDetailsCRM);` on top of my class and reused it all the time without putting it into `using`. Thanks to this action I didn't have to attach anything prior to saving or anything. I was just using same context and attached any foreign keys I wanted using `currentUczestnik.Szkolenie = szkolenie;` and currentUczestnik.Konsultanci = consultants;. It saved without problems.
2. Instead of attaching whole object like `currentUczestnik.Szkolenie = szkolenie;` I've added it thru EntityKey on SzkolenieReference and SzkolenieID.

   ```
   context.Attach(szkolenie);
   context.Szkolenies.Attach(szkolenie);
   currentUczestnik.SzkolenieReference.EntityKey = szkolenie.EntityKey;
   currentUczestnik.SzkolenieID = szkolenie.SzkolenieID;
   ```
3. Solution number 3 was to create new object based on on old object. The referenced Konsultanci and Szkolenia are kind of resynchronized (I think it's actually retaking them from db).

   ```
    using (var context = new EntityBazaCRM(Settings.sqlDataConnectionDetailsCRM)) {
                   if (currentUczestnik.SzkolenieUczestnicyID == 0) {
                       var nowy = new SzkolenieUczestnicy {
                           Konsultanci = context.Konsultancis.First(p => p.KonsultantNazwa == currentUczestnik.Konsultanci.KonsultantNazwa),
                           Szkolenie = context.Szkolenies.First(p => p.SzkolenieID == varSzkolenie.SzkolenieID),
                           SzkolenieUzytkownik = currentUczestnik.SzkolenieUzytkownik,
                           SzkolenieUzytkownikData = currentUczestnik.SzkolenieUzytkownikData,
                           UczestnikPotwierdzilUdzial = currentUczestnik.UczestnikPotwierdzilUdzial,
                           UczestnikPrzybyl = currentUczestnik.UczestnikPrzybyl
                       };


                       context.SzkolenieUczestnicies.AddObject(nowy);
                       context.SaveChanges();
                       listaDoPodmiany.Add(nowy);
   ```
4. Solution number 4 is what I ended up using. Basically it's null-ing any referenced objects (first temporary saving them to objects) and then using just their ID values before save. Then after save objects are reattached.

   ```
           foreach (SzkolenieUczestnicy uczestnik in listaUczestnikow.Objects) {
               using (var context = new EntityBazaCRM(Settings.sqlDataConnectionDetailsCRM)) {
                   if (uczestnik.SzkolenieUczestnicyID == 0) { // add new object
                       var konsultant = uczestnik.Konsultanci; 
                       uczestnik.Konsultanci = null; // null attached object and reuse it's ID later on for SAVE purposes
                       uczestnik.KonsultantNazwa = konsultant.KonsultantNazwa;
                       uczestnik.Szkolenie = null; // null attached object and reuse it's ID later on for SAVE purposes
                       uczestnik.SzkolenieID = szkolenie.SzkolenieID;                       
                       context.SzkolenieUczestnicies.AddObject(uczestnik);
                       context.SaveChanges();
                       context.Detach(uczestnik); // detatch to prevent Context problems
                       uczestnik.Szkolenie = szkolenie;// reassign for use in ObjectListView
                       uczestnik.Konsultanci = konsultant; // reassign for use in ObjectListView
                   } else { // modify exisinng object 
                       context.SzkolenieUczestnicies.Attach(uczestnik);

                      //context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(uczestnik, EntityState.Modified);
                       context.SaveChanges();
                   }
               }
           }
   ```

Comment: I would vote for solution 1. I think it has benefits to have a context lifetime in line with window lifetime in a Winforms application, especially you have the full benefit of change tracking of attached objects.

Comment: Questions is will it survive in more complicated circumstances like multithreading and such. Or when there will be 50 objects etc.

Comment: I have added another solution. This seems to work just fine and can have non global context. It's just I think it's regetting Konsultanci, Szkolenie reference back from db.